# Apache Server Won't Start in MAMP

Tags: apache, mamp

Apache server won't start when in MAMP.  Here are the error logs:

```
[Wed Aug 01 21:07:34 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Aug 01 21:07:34 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Aug 01 21:07:34 2012] [notice] Apache/2.0.63 (Unix) PHP/5.3.2 DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 01 21:08:00 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Aug 01 21:08:01 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Aug 01 21:08:01 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Aug 01 21:08:01 2012] [notice] Apache/2.0.63 (Unix) PHP/5.3.2 DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 01 21:08:51 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

I don't think I did anything our of the ordinary except create a new folder in htdocs.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just reinstalled MAMP and changed the ports.  Not sure what the problem was, but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 81):

My solution:
in /Applications/Mamp/Library/bin, find the file envvars and rename it to _envvars.

now it works.

Comment: No idea how this fixed it. Thanks :)

Comment: This fixed it. Any idea why?

Comment: It's Yosemite "things"... Yosemite changed some apache module location, so old envvars couldn't find it. Mamp posted: https://twitter.com/mamp_en/status/496668261619335169

Comment: Also fixed it for me when it stopped working upgrading to OS Sierra. Thanks!

Comment: Sadly this didnt work for me on OS High Sierra 10.3.1 (Dec 18th 2017)

Answer (score 18):

I encountered this same issue with the same log output above, but did not need to reinstall MAMP to solve the issue in my case. When I encountered this error it was related to one of the hosts I had set up. Click the Hosts tab and see if any of your hosts appear in red:

[image]

The host in red required SSL certificates. In the configuration I did not have valid references to the required certificates after I had altered the file structure of my application. After fixing this issue and applying changes the host was no longer highlighted in red, and I was able to start Apache through MAMP.

Additionally, you can ensure that the problem doesn't have to do with your Apache client itself by running this command in terminal:

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl restart
```

OR

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP\ PRO/Library/bin/apachectl restart
```

If you are able to start Apache in terminal, you have ruled out that you have an error with MAMP's Apache client itself.

Comment: This solution worked well for me. It's definitely preferable to re-installing MAMP, which is a very large app.

Comment: sudo /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl restart - seems to fixed my issue thanks much

Comment: This was the solution for me also. I'd shifted/re-organized some folders which included my local SSL CRT/KEY files. Thanks @quetzaluz

Comment: I had a red arrow near apache in MAMP PRO 4.5 but I couldn’t find the host that was causing the issue. I’ve deleted all the hosts one by one and suddenly the red arrow disappeared. There was one host with an issue. APACHE was able to start then.

Answer (score 17):

Change the name of the file envvars to _envvars in /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin , thats it .

Answer (score 7):

Instead of reinstalling mamp I did the following:

```
1. Moved back to default mamp ports
2. Started mamp   
3. Stopped mamp 
4. Went back to ports 80 443 3306
```

and it started working.

Comment: ah nice! that solved it... more problems with MAMP Pro compared to MAMP basic.. real shame

Answer (score 0):

If your existing MAMP PRO suddenly won't start Apache anymore, then it might be an error in vhosts settings which is not visible.

There is often no indication in apache_error.log - it just comes up with the message.

```
Apache wasn't able to start. Please check log for more information.
```

In my case it was a wrong path in Customized virtual host settings such as

```
Include /path/to/project/rewrite.conf
```

Vhost config is saved in ~/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/httpd.conf so you can check the settings there.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution: MAMP 4 - Dec 2017, *macOS High Sierra*

Had this issue with MAMP Pro 3.4.1 so i paid for a new license so i could upgrade to Version 4.2.1 and the problem still occurred. I tried the above solution and unfortunately had no luck.

I did however get Apache running again by selection **all** options for the directory directive as shown in the image below:

[image: MAMP Pro 4.2.1 - Apache <Directory> Directive]

This issue occurred completely randomly, one day everything working fine then the next... Apache says no. I believe the issue is that like web browsers use a Cache and separately also hold open processes, i think sometimes when MAMP or MAMP Pro is not closed properly then it can screw up Apache because it is not stopped correctly.

I hope this answer helps any persons experiencing this issue!

Answer (score 0):

In case above answers didn't fix it, you can check that Document Root isn't set on some non-existing directory.
Go to MAMP Settings > Web-Server > Document Root

Answer (score 0):

I found a Solution:

JUST:

in /Applications/Mamp/Library/bin, find the file **envvars** and rename it to **_envvars**.

Answer (score -2):

this issue comes to me today … 
after trying several solutions, i found this dialog message may appear if MAMP no longer finds a certificate used by a securized localhost.
So be careful to keep them in a place you won't move or delete.

hope it helps